# Pairing BLE device on Android pops up two dialogs

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, pairing, bounding

Calling `device.connectGatt(appCtx, autoConnect, getCentralGattCallback());` where

- `device` is a discovered BLE device that was not paired (bonded) before
- `getCentralGattCallback()` returns callback implementation that's not relevant in this context, we can assume it just logs callbacks

will pop up the system pair confirmation dialog (notifications, actually) 2 times in a row. Those dialogs are exactly the same, just pair and cancel buttons. Only after confirming the second one, callback's `onConnectionStateChange` will be fired.

That's not the best user experience and I wonder if I should dig deeper into my code and find the root problem for this, or it's an Android bug?

---

###### Reproducible on:

Central: Pixel 4a, Android 12
Peripheral: Nonin 3230 Oximeter (also A&D Weight Scales and Blood Pressure Monitor wors the same way)

*That's not the case for OnePlus 5T, Android 10 thought - just 1 pair confirmation is required here.*

Comment: Seems more like a bug, since the bonding process is handled by the system.